# IDE для программирование под Linux

Tags: ide, gcc, g++

У меня установлена Debian на VMware и мне нужно писать ПО с gcc в основном, но иногда и g++.

Так вот сейчас у меня есть общая папка Windows с VMware, и я пишу в notepad++, вручную пишу makefile's и компилирую.

Мне нужна IDE для Windows с которой я смогу писать ПО для gcc И g++. 
В EDI должны работать подсказки и ctrl+space. А так же на ctrl+space были как мои функции и объекты с header файлов так и системные.

Есть ли такой EDI?

Или как вообще программируют под Linux с Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

QtCreator вам нужен. Все, что вы просите, в нем есть. И Makefile руками ваять не нужно.

Есть еще KDevelop, но после третьей версии он омонстрел.

И Code::Blocks. Но он глюковат.

Comment: QtCreator Громоздкий, да и заточен для Qt. А у меня несколько Linux установлено + разные архитектуры включая mips. Попробовал Qt, что то тяжеловата в настройки. Скачал netbeans, вроде нормально.

Comment: @CJ1 - ну, если пара мегабайт самого криэйтора - это тяжелый, то я не знаю. 
Qt настраивать не нужно - она сама работает (если не искать приключений), тем более что криэйтор умеет создавать приложения без Qt.

Answer (score 6):

Если вас:

- тянет на **приключения** (а они **будут**)
- вполне устраивает сборка через `Makefile` (но не хочется её дергать из терминала)
- устраивает висящий в системе `clang` (для сборки его использовать необязательно)

...то можете попробовать [Atom](https://atom.io/), сделав после установки:

```
apm install linter linter-clang autocomplete-clang build build-make
```

- `linter-clang` использует `clang` для поиска ошибок.
- `autocomplete-clang` обеспечивает автодополнение, а также "перейти к определению", тоже на основе `clang`.
- `build`+`build-make` обеспечивают обнаружение `Makefile`, таргетов внутри него и использование его по сочетанию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, а также выводят ошибки сборки в `linter`.
- `linter` выводит ошибки, о которых ему сообщили провайдеры (`build`, `linter-clang`) единым списком в настраиваемом виде и позволяет быстро к ним переходить.

Использовать это для профессиональной разработки на C++ так себе (в особенности, из-за отсутствия нормального отладчика), но для небольших программок очень даже годится.

**Выглядит это примерно так** (цветовая схема требует доработки, это да):

[image: внешний вид Atom с C++]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Atom это для хипстеров, которых тянет на приключения. Python, lua, Ruby и прочие модные вещи его стезя. Бородатые C-прогеры выбирают vim. Возможности по расширению гораздо выше, куча модулей и дополнений, а также туториалов по всему интернету. (на правах холивара)

Comment: @jumpjet67 не забудьте оставить ответ со своими рекомендациями по разработке на C/C++ в Vim :)

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text 3 с дополнениями и будет просто шик)

Answer (score -1):

Clion от jetbrains - это лучший вариант. Там и make файл не надо самому писать. По нажатию кнопки ещё и инсталлер на питоне делает. И вообще, работать с ним одно удовольствие

Comment: Ответ должен быть развёрнутым и на русском языке.